# How to monitor CPU usage automatically and return results when it reaches a threshold

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am new to shell script , i want to write a script to monitor CPU usage and if the CPU usage reaches a threshold it should print the CPU usage by top command ,here is my script , which is giving me error bad number and also not storing any value in the log files

```
while sleep 1;do if [ "$(top -n1 | grep -i ^cpu | awk '{print $2}')">>sy.log - ge "$Threshold" ]; then echo "$(top -n1)">>sys.log;fi;done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script HAS to be indented and stored to a file, especially if you are new to shell !

```
#!/bin/sh

while sleep 1
do 
    if [ "$(top -n1 | grep -i ^cpu | awk '{print $2}')">>sy.log - ge "$Threshold" ]
then
    echo "$(top -n1)"  >>  sys.log
fi
done
```

Your condition looks a bit odd. It may work, but it looks really complex. Store intermediate results in variables, and evaluate them.
Then, you will immediately see the syntax error on the “-ge”.

You HAVE to store logfiles within an absolute path for security reasons. Use variables to simplify the reading.

```
#!/bin/sh

LOGFILE=/absolute_path/sy.log
WHOLEFILE=/absolute_path/sys.log
Thresold=80

while sleep 1
do 
   TOP="$(top -n1)"
   CPU="$(echo $TOP | grep -i ^cpu | awk '{print $2}')"
   echo $CPU >> $LOGFILE
   if [ "$CPU" -ge "$Threshold" ] ; then
       echo "$TOP"  >>  $WHOLEFILE
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors.

- If you write output to `sy.log` with a redirection then that output is no longer available to the shell.  You can work around this with `tee`.
- The dash before `-ge` must not be followed by a space.

Also, a few stylistic remarks:

- `grep x | awk '{y}'` is a [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep); this can usefully and more economically (as well as more elegantly) be rewritten as `awk '/x/{y}'`
- `echo "$(command)"` is a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) -- not a deal-breaker, but you simply want `command`; there is no need to capture what it prints to standard output just so you can print that text to standard output.
- If you are going to capture the output of `top -n 1` anyway, there is no need really to run it twice.

Further notes:

- If you know the capitalization of the field you want to extract, maybe you don't need to search case-insensitively. (I could not find a version of `top` which prints a CPU prefix with the load in the second field -- it the expression really correct?)
- The shell only supports integer arithmetic. Is this a bug? Maybe you want to use Awk (which has floating-point support) to perform the comparison?  This also allows for a moderately tricky refactoring.  We make Awk output an exit code of 1 if the comparison fails, and use that as the condition for the `if`.

```
#!/bin/sh

while sleep 1
do
    if top=$(top -n 1 |
        awk -v thres="$Threshold" '1; # print every line
            tolower($1) ~ /^cpu/ { print $2 >>"sy.log";
                exitcode = ($2 >= thres ? 0 : 1) }
            END { exit exitcode }')
    then
        echo "$top" >>sys.log
    fi
done
```

Do you really mean to have two log files with nearly the same name, or is that a typo? Including a time stamp in the log might be useful both for troubleshooting and for actually using the log files.